# How to add an array/list to an object

Tags: arrays, r, list, oop

I create a student class with :

```
setClass("student", slots=list(name="character", age="numeric", GPA="numeric"))
```

Now I want to create another class :

```
setClass("classRoom", slots=list(id = "numeric"),contains = "student")
```

only issue is instead of one student I want to add a list of students.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can  make another class "students", which will have a list/array of students, and then use that class inside the definition of class "classRoom".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have already achieved what you wanted.
Adding student class in classRoom will give access to all the properties of class student. You can now enter new students in classRoom with the properties of class student.

```
# define a class called student
setClass("student", slots=list(name="character", age="numeric", GPA="numeric"))

# inherit from student
setClass("classRoom", slots=list(id = "numeric"),contains = "student")

# Now create new objects of classroom:
> s1 <- new("classRoom",name="John", age=21, GPA=3.5, id=001)
> s2 <- new("classRoom",name="Grisham", age=24, GPA=345, id=002)
> s3 <- new("classRoom",name="Flamingo", age=22, GPA=3.8, id=003)
```

Like this, you have added students in your classRoom.